# Can not connect to Glassfish connection pool

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish

I can not connect from java to Glassfish connection pool.
There is exception -  javax.naming.NoInitialContextException

In Glassfish admin:
1. I created JDBC Connection Pool, named it ‘PaymentSys’, and I can ping it.
2. I created JDBC Resource, named it ‘jdbc/paymentSys’ and link it to connection pool ‘PaymentSys’.

In java code I wrote:

```
public Connection getConnection(){
        Connection conn=null;
        String dataSourceContext = "java:comp/env/jdbc/paymentSys";
        try{
        InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) context.lookup(dataSourceContext);
        conn = ds.getConnection();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }               
        return conn;
    }
```

I tried in dataSourceContext use 'jdbc/paymentSys', but it was not useful.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in insert sql command.